# queryText being sent to Dialogflow is not the original user query

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

The user input / queryText being sent to Dialogflow is not the expected, original user query.

[simulator query manipulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPx0Y.png)

I enabled "Log interactions to Google Cloud" in my Dialogflow project's settings. What I'm seeing is multiple "assistant_action" resources before the actual request that goes to DF. In the example above, this is what I see:

[GCP logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frnJq.png)

With the first debug resource showing post data with:

```
"inputs":[{"rawInputs":[{"inputType":"UNSPECIFIED_INPUT_TYPE","query":"how long has it been on the market"}]
```

And

```
resource: {
type: "assistant_action"
  labels: {
    project_id: "<MY-PROJECT-ID>"
    version_id: ""
    action_id: ""
  }
},
timestamp: "2021-03-05T18:41:44.142202856Z"
severity: "DEBUG"
labels: {
  channel: "production"
  querystream: "GOOGLE_USER"
  source: "AOG_REQUEST_RESPONSE"
}
```

The subsequent requests are the same but with modified input queries ("how long has it been on the market" -> "how long has something been on the market" -> "how long has us FDA been on the market"), the last one being the actual user query sent, the channel being preview and the action_id "actions.intent.TEXT".

```
resource: {
type: "assistant_action"
  labels: {
    project_id: "<MY-PROJECT-ID>"
    version_id: ""
    action_id: "actions.intent.TEXT"
  }
},
timestamp: "2021-03-05T18:41:45.942019959Z"
severity: "DEBUG"
labels: {
  channel: "preview"
  querystream: "GOOGLE_USER"
  source: "AOG_REQUEST_RESPONSE"
}
```

I should note that I am testing current drafts of an AoG project and have no releases let alone a production release. I have a denied beta, because of branding issues which I address with separate AoG/DF projects for PROD. I do not have any intents enabled for slot filling or any required entity parameters. This is just one example, but I have been noticing many occurrences of this issue.

What is happening here? Why is the original user input being manipulated? What are all these interactions we are seeing before the expected request/response cycle?

Comment: Is this only happening when you use the word "this", and does it seem to be replacing "this" with something you recently mentioned?

Comment: @Prisoner not just "this", other prepositions too. And it is not simply replacing that word.

Comment: @Prisoner Sometimes this manipulation is done on a significant part of the utterance.

Example:
 - User input 1: <drug_name>
 - Actual user input 2: "can you tell me about its efficacy"
 - Recorded/sent user input 2: "effectiveness of <drug_name>" 

Are you aware of how AoG handles entity resolution? I'm seeing this sort of behaviour with entities/parts of an utterance that I don't have anywhere in my Agent, not just <drug_name> and other entities.

Comment: If I input "Lorem", I get a fallback as expected. If I then enter "can you tell me about its dosage", the user query sent to DF is "lorem ipsum dosage". Where is this coming from? And how can I disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

After having contacted someone at Google Cloud, I was informed this was something that had been raised by others and that AoG devs were looking into it.

As of a Mar 24 2021 release, I can no longer replicate this Entity Resolution issue.